# Adding new Icons to MUI library

Tags: icons, react-icons, appicon, libiconv, application-icon

Is it possible to add new icons to MUI Library ?
Please help us find some workarounds to add icons to the library.
I coudld not able to find the appropiate icon for my product, so trying to add some custom MUI icons which is not availbale in MUI library.
Thank You